# Mricron installation problem?

Tags: 14.04, uninstall

I am a new Linux user. I installed the current version of Mricron according to the instructions of it's website.  But program does not run when I type "startmricro" on the terminal or double click on the mricron app. And also I tried to uninstall the program but I couldn't find it in Ubuntu Software Center. Could you please help me to run the program or uninstall it?

Output of `apt-cache policy mricron`

```
mricron:
     Installed: (none)
     Candidate: 0.20120505.1~dfsg.1-1 
     Version table:
        0.20120505.1~dfsg.1-1 0
          500 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/universe amd64 Packages 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Ubuntu version? Add the output of `apt-cache policy mricron` to your question,please

Comment: My ubuntu version: 14.04.3 LTS \n \l

Comment: mricron:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.20120505.1~dfsg.1-1
  Version table:
     0.20120505.1~dfsg.1-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/677712/edit) your question add the same ,please

Comment: I am sorry but I did not understand. What do you mean by " edit your question add the same ,please"

Comment: ok, ignore it, open software centre and search for `mricron` and install

Comment: Yes I can do it but this is the ls output of /usr/local/bin : mricro  mricrox.tar.gz  startmricro  startmricro2  startmricro64

Comment: Already there are mricron files. Should I move them trash before instal a new one

Comment: how you installed `mricron` previously!

Comment: I installed it according to the instructions of its website. http://www.mccauslandcenter.sc.edu/mricro/mricron/install.html

Comment: follow my answer then comment under answer!

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>,then run the commands,

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo rm mricro mricrox.tar.gz startmricro startmricro2 startmricro64
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mricron
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29521/discussion-on-answer-by-ravan-mricron-installation-problem).